# How to freeze picamera preview

Tags: python, camera, raspberry-pi3, freeze

I want to start a camera preview which takes a picture after some time using the PiCamera Module, and when the picture was taken it should frezze the preview so the user can view it, how can i freeze the preview?

Currently I display it using matplotlib.image:

```py
from picamera import PiCamera
from time import sleep
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg

def btn_press(channel):
    camera.start_preview()
    camera.annotate_text="3..."
    sleep(1)
    camera.annotate_text="2..."
    sleep(1)
    camera.annotate_text="1..."
    sleep(1)
    camera.capture("image.jpg")
    camera.annotate_text="Pic taken"
    sleep(5)
    camera.stop_preview()
    pic=mpimg.imread("image.jpg")
    plt.imshow(pic)
    plt.show()
    #print("pic taken")

camera = PiCamera()
camera.led=False
camera.annotate_text_size=100

btn=20

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(20, GPIO.IN)

GPIO.add_event_detect(btn, GPIO.BOTH, callback=btn_press, bouncetime=8000)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of doing this but you could use

```
plt.waitforbuttonpress()
```